# Django ListView: 'this_object_id' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-listview

I keep having issues when I want to refer to a specific object in `ListView`.

My views:

```
class SongList(generic.ListView):
    model = models.Song
    template_name = 'videos/song_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'song_list'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SongList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user_flash = Flashcard.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user).values_list('question', flat=True)
        song = models.Song.objects.get(pk=this_object_id)  #works if hard-coded
        lyrics_list = models.Song.objects.get(song=song).lyrics_as_list()
        user_word = list(set(user_flash) & set(lyrics_list))
        context['percent_known'] = (len(user_word)/len(set((lyrics_list))))*100
        return context
```

I get the following error: `name 'this_object_id' is not defined`

I've tried various variations, but I keep getting errors, e.g.

```
self.kwargs['pk']
self.kwargs.get['pk']
```

Then I get the error: `KeyError 'pk'`

It works when I hard-code the pk, so the problem is not elsewhere my code. It also works when I do it in my `DetailView` (using `self.kwargs['pk']`), but I need access to `percent_known` for every object in my `ListView`. How can I do this? I can sort of understand why it doesn't work, `ListView` is for a list of objects, so it doesn't know for what object I want to get this info for... but there must be a way I can do it for every object? Or is there another way to get access to `percent_known` for every object?

Comment: Well is there in the `path(..)` to this listivew a `pk` path parameter?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem No, there isn't, but if I put a `pk` in the path, will it still be able to show a list of all objects?

Comment: You just can't have access to Song id in get_context_data. As you said, it is for list of objects. First place where you can access Song id is your template when you render your table(?). My idea is to write custom templatetag or filter and pass id to it and calculate your percent_known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here is that in the `get_context_data()` method you are trying to access information for a single item, when you are actually managing a list.

If you have some difficult calculations to perform for every object of your list, you can access those objects in the `get_context_data()`, like:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        for song in context['song_list']:
             # Here you already have the current Song object you want to process
             lyrics_list = models.Song.objects.get(song=song).lyrics_as_list()

             # and so on...
        
        return context
```

Another more efficient option would be to perform this calculations using the Django ORM system, [annotating](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/) the `Song`s list under the `get_queryset()` method.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Your first suggestion worked. I'm not sure how to do the second, but I'll look into it later.

Comment: Glad to hear that! In the link I included you should find the starting point for that. The basic idea is that instead of doing all those calculations in a different query for every item on the loop, you make a single database hit annotating your results.